# React Using Hook set state undefined when trying delete each item

Tags: reactjs

[image]

i using react hooks and got undefined in function 'deletePersonHandler' on 'setPersonsState'.
on the tutorial using 'this.setstate' can delete each item,buat when i trying
all data deleted and didn't return.
when i see the log 'setPersonsState' 'undefined'
[solved with this](https://www.taniarascia.com/crud-app-in-react-with-hooks/)

but still cant set that state,

```
Person.js

     <div className="Person">
          <p>I'm a {props.name} I am {props.age} years old! {props.children}</p>
          <button onClick={props.click}>{props.name} index: {props.indexData}</button>
          <input type="text" onChange={props.changed} value={props.name} />
     </div>
```

```
App.js


// React hooks
const App = () => {
  // state
  // array destructuring
  const [personsState, setPersonsState] = useState({
    persons: [
      { name: 'Max', age: 28 },
      { name: 'Manu', age: 29 },
      { name: 'Stephanie', age: 30 }
    ],
    otherState: [{ phone: '+628762663994' }],
    showPersons: true,
  });

  //Event onClick
  const deletePersonHandler = (personIndex) => {
    const persons = personsState.persons;
    persons.splice(personIndex, 1);
    setPersonsState({ persons: persons });

    console.log(persons);
    console.log(setPersonsState({ persons: persons }));

  };
  // End Event

  //element
  let persons = null;
  if (personsState.showPersons) {
    persons = (
      <div>
        {personsState.persons.map((person, index) => {
          return <Person
            click={() => deletePersonHandler(index)}
            indexData={index}
            name={person.name}
            age={person.age}
            changed={(setNameChange) => nameChangeHandler(setNameChange)} />
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
  //end element

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello React</h1>
      <button className="button-cus"
        // onClick={() => switchNameHandle('Button')}>Switch Name</button>
        onClick={() => tooglePersonsHandler()}>Toogle Name</button>
      {persons}
    </div >
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this and check live https://vvhoy.csb.app/

```
  const deletePersonHandler = item => {
    console.log(item);
    let filtered = personsState.persons.filter(
      person => person.age !== item.age
    );
    setPersonsState({ ...personsState, persons: filtered });
  };
```

pass complete object `deletePersonHandler(person)`

```
    <div>
        {personsState.persons.map((person, index) => {
          return <Person
            click={() => deletePersonHandler(person)}
            indexData={index}
            name={person.name}
            age={person.age}
            changed={(setNameChange) => nameChangeHandler(setNameChange)} />
        })}
      </div>
```

[Live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-night-vvhoy)

Comment: still undefined

Comment: it work thank,let me understand it thank you for help

Comment: @Piter if it's helpful for you please accept/vote for this...thanks

Answer (score 1):

Replace this lane
const persons = personsState.persons;
By
const persons = [...personsState.persons];
you need to include previous state like that setPersonsState({...personsState, persons}) or you delete the showPersons state which cause the if to be false

Comment: And the undefined from the function call is due to the fact that the function return nothing.

Comment: i already changed the const with const persons = [...personsState.persons];
but still undefiend.

Comment: i am confused about the tutorial using this.setstate its work well but when i use hook i set my code like ``` setPersonsState({ persons: persons });``` when i console.log that undefined hmm

Comment: Oh I just realised your error, when you call setPersonsState(..) you need to include previous state like that detPersonsState({...personsState, persons}) or you delete the showPersons state which cause the if to be false.

Answer (score 0):

```
const deletePersonHandler = (personIndex) => {
    //dont use splice because react state must be immutable
    setPersonsState({
        persons: personsState.persons.slice(0, index).concat(personsState.persons.slice(index + 1)),
        otherState: personsState.otherState,
        showPersons: personsState.showPersons
    });
};
```

I hope it works

Comment: this also work,thank Man.
let me understand it 2 diffrent code form Man and Vahid Akhtar

Comment: don't mutate state